# _TypeError (type '(dynamic) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => void' of 'action')

Tags: flutter

i am doing GET api then specialized to model and i am getting this error, i am not sure what to do

json Link : https://api-zingmp3-vercel.vercel.app/api/home

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Genmd.png)

Comment: Add your code snippet in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (json['items'] != null) {

  json['items'].forEach((e) {
    items.add(Item.fromJson(e));
});
...
}
```

Try changing the code above to A, B and C.

A

```
  if (json['items'] != null) {

     var itemBox = json[“items"] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
     itemBox.forEach((e) {
        items.add(Item.fromJson(e));
     });
     ...
  }
```

B

```
  if (json['items'] != null) {

     var itemBox = json[“items"] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
     itemBox.map<Item>((e) => testList.add(Item.fromJson(e)) as Item);
     ...
  }
```

C

```
 if (json['items'] != null) {

    items = List<Item>.from(
    (json['items'] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>).map((x) => Item.fromJson(x)));
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should cast the json item list before calling `forEach()`:

```
(json['items'] as List).forEach()
```